# Cannot restore nuget packages of mono project under Gitlab CI docker environment

Tags: docker, nuget, gitlab-ci

The project in developed under Mono and depends on some nuget packages. I use Gitlab CI to run builds. The build environment is docker ubuntu. All other `apt-get` installations work perfectly but nuget never restores the packages no matter how I modify the parameters and `NuGet.config`. I switched between v2 and v3 and tried everything discussed in what I can find on the internet:

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

http://docs.myget.org/docs/how-to/package-not-found-during-package-restore

but still gets the following errors:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.1.4 (9e2fd1a)
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.1 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.1 ...
...
$ apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq
$ apt-get install -y -qq mono-complete
...
$ wget https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe
...
$ mono nuget.exe restore monotest.sln -Source http://nuget.org/api/v2
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0' from '/usr/lib/mono/4.5'.
Restoring NuGet package MongoDB.Bson.2.2.3.
Restoring NuGet package MongoDB.Driver.2.2.3.
Restoring NuGet package MongoDB.Driver.Core.2.2.3.
Restoring NuGet package Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3.
WARNING: Unable to find version '2.2.3' of package 'MongoDB.Bson'.
  /root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache: Package 'MongoDB.Bson.2.2.3' is not found on source '/root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache'.
  http://nuget.org/api/v2: Unable to load the service index for source http://nuget.org/api/v2.
  This method must be implemented in derived classes

WARNING: Unable to find version '8.0.3' of package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
  /root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache: Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3' is not found on source '/root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache'.
  http://nuget.org/api/v2: Unable to load the service index for source http://nuget.org/api/v2.
  This method must be implemented in derived classes

WARNING: Unable to find version '2.2.3' of package 'MongoDB.Driver'.
  /root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache: Package 'MongoDB.Driver.2.2.3' is not found on source '/root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache'.
  http://nuget.org/api/v2: Unable to load the service index for source http://nuget.org/api/v2.
  This method must be implemented in derived classes

WARNING: Unable to find version '2.2.3' of package 'MongoDB.Driver.Core'.
  /root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache: Package 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.2.2.3' is not found on source '/root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache'.
  http://nuget.org/api/v2: Unable to load the service index for source http://nuget.org/api/v2.
  This method must be implemented in derived classes


Errors in packages.config projects
    Unable to find version '2.2.3' of package 'MongoDB.Bson'.
      /root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache: Package 'MongoDB.Bson.2.2.3' is not found on source '/root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache'.
      http://nuget.org/api/v2: Unable to load the service index for source http://nuget.org/api/v2.
      This method must be implemented in derived classes
    Unable to find version '8.0.3' of package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
      /root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache: Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3' is not found on source '/root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache'.
      http://nuget.org/api/v2: Unable to load the service index for source http://nuget.org/api/v2.
      This method must be implemented in derived classes
    Unable to find version '2.2.3' of package 'MongoDB.Driver'.
      /root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache: Package 'MongoDB.Driver.2.2.3' is not found on source '/root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache'.
      http://nuget.org/api/v2: Unable to load the service index for source http://nuget.org/api/v2.
      This method must be implemented in derived classes
    Unable to find version '2.2.3' of package 'MongoDB.Driver.Core'.
      /root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache: Package 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.2.2.3' is not found on source '/root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache'.
      http://nuget.org/api/v2: Unable to load the service index for source http://nuget.org/api/v2.
      This method must be implemented in derived classes

NuGet Config files used:
    /builds/renkun-ken/monotest/.nuget/NuGet.config
    /root/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    /root/.local/share/NuGet/Cache
    http://nuget.org/api/v2

ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

References:

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference

On my local machine I can successfully restore all packages from online source with exactly the same commands.

Comment: What's in your nuget.conf? I had to add respository sources to mine **and still**  specifically add a number of package downloads using the -Source parameter to _nuget install_. It seems that some packages do not show up properly with _nuget restore_, so I simply forced their download. I use Bamboo for builds.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Ubuntu you're using, adding `ca-certificates-mono` to your environment may help:

```
apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated ca-certificates-mono
```

I'm using Docker with Stretch and [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/168) fixed my identical issue to yours.